# Typescript. Template default value for class shared between two projects

Tags: typescript, templates

I have a .ts file with a class that declared with templates. This class shared between two applications(client and server). Each application use this class with different template types.

And I want to declare this class with default parameter for client.

Now I do it like that:

```js
import {ISender, Base} from './ISender';
import {ClientSender} from '../client/src/app/interfaceImpl/ClientSender';

export class DFEnumBSTR<T extends ISender = ClientSender> extends Base<T>{
    constructor(id: string, sender: new (id: string) => T) {
        super(id, sender);
    }
...
}
```

But when I compile server application it also compile `'../client/src/app/interfaceImpl/ClientSender'` with all his dependencies.

Is it possible to ignore this import for server project?

Or maybe there have some way like in C++ when in .h file can you just declare exist type(`class ClientSender;`) and specify this type in .cpp by including file with this type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
Near each type that can be passed as template parameter, I should add type alias:

`export type Sender = ClientSender`

And configure for each project "path aliases".

For Node.JS: https://dev.to/lars124/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353

For Angular: https://christianlydemann.com/simpler-typescript-paths-with-path-aliases/

And now my shared module looks like:

```js
import {ISender, Base} from './ISender';
import {Sender} from '@sender/';

export class DFEnumBSTR<T extends ISender = Sender> extends Base<T>{
    constructor(id: string, sender: new (id: string) => T) {
        super(id, sender);
    }
...
}
```